# Move View go over another View - Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on an app that uses the UIPanGestureRecognizer to move Views.

I need to move the view 'Blue' in my self.view, and when the view 'Blue' go over another view (subview - with other colors - from self.view), the subview change color by the color blue.

I need to **drag the 'blue view' over the other views**, and **identify** which **view** is being **overlapped**. And to get the view overlapped, I need to change the background color to blue.

It is possible?

I tried using CGRectContainsPoint but I can not get the view that is above my 'view blue'.

My storyboard:

[image]

and my Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var panView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        panView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panViewGesture:"))
    }

    func panViewGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let locationInView = sender.locationInView(self.view)

        if sender.state == .Changed {

            panView.frame.origin = locationInView

        }

    }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Right now your question is very broad. You'll have better luck getting an answer if you post what you've tried and a specific problem you're running into.

Comment: @CleverError I updated my question, can you help me?

Comment: @James did you work it out?